# Overlap size fixed block with flex div rows and columns with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, overlay, overlap

I summarize by colors what I need to do with this body structure.

Yellow: this block is a nav bar, always visible on top.
Red/Grey : this has to be the same background-color, it's the content of the website. Grey block is still stuck at the bottom and should be overlapped by others div (green and side menu on the right).
Green : Still stuck at the bottom as well but always visible when the window is reduced. (should not be overlapped by right side menu).
Blue/Orange/Purple (right side menu)
Blue: 10% height and 100% width
Orange/Purple : same height 45% and 100% width. When the window reduces, the proportions remain the same and an overflow: auto is applied on each part.

Now, my problem is for grey and right side menu (Orange/Purple) blocks. 
When I reduce the window these blocks are not overlapped and a scroll bar appears on the right, I don't want that.
The structure should stay like this one and with flex elements : [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtLev.png)

Here the bootply : https://www.bootply.com/BGNEWBBsc5

Comment: Its working fine for me

Comment: Sorry but not for me, see here : https://imgur.com/fJFny5Q

Comment: Well in that case in `vw` like` font-size:1vw;`